# Noise removal from a matrix when the noise covariance structure is known

Tags: covariance-matrix, matrix, noise

I have a matrix made by the addition of the signal and the noise. I know the covariance structure of the noise but don't have the actual noise matrix. Is there a way to remove the noise/obtain an estimate of the matrix without the noise?